# Что значит n% и как работает выражение n%9 or n and 9 в целом?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def digital_root(n):
    print(n%9 or n and 9)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: `%` — mod... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Мне в комментариях указали на ошибку в моих рассуждениях, поэтому я переписал ответ. И, фактически, автором ответа является dIm0n ( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/398802/dim0n )

Давайте попробуем разобрать это выражение вместе.

`%` - это операция `остаток от деления`. Например, `19%5 = 4`

or - это или, and - это и.

И здесь начинается самое интересное, а именно: "В языке Python операторы and и or, как вы и ожидали, выполняют булевы операции, но они не возвращают булевы значения: результатом всегда является значение одного из операндов.

Для оператора and: При использовании оператора and, значения вычисляются в булевом контексте слева напрво. Значения 0, '', [], (), {} и None являются ложью, все остальное является истиной

Если какой-либо из операндов является ложью, результатом будет первое такое значение.

Если все значения являются истиной, так что в результате мы получаем последнее значение.

Аналогично для оператора or: при вычислении значения цепочки переменных, связанных or, будет возвращено значение первого операнда, который интерпретируется как "истина". (в случае чисел - первого  ненулевого операнда). Если ВСЕ операнды в цепочке - ложь, то будет возвращено значение последнего"

Ну, и еще у нас есть приоритет операций. Приритет операций описан в разделе 6.17 доков по третьему питону, и, как и ожидаемо, сначала по приоритету идет вычисленеи остатка от деления, потом по приоритету идет `and` и наконец по риоритету следует `or`

Теперь смотрим, как это практически работает.

Сначала будет вычислен остаток от деления. Промежуточно назовем его my_mod

А потом, так как следующим выражением является or, происходит такой фокус: если my_mod не равен нулю - мы заканчиваем вычисления. И результатом вычислений будет my_mod.

Для меня лично это был довольно токий момент. (не совсем то, чего ожидаешь, когда знаешь, что у and приоритет выше.)

А вот если my_mod равно нулю - вот тогда будет вычислено (n and 9), в результате получим 9, если n>0.

Потом, так как my_mod равен нулю, происходит вычисление (my_mod or 9), в результате которого возвращается 9.

Значит, будет возвращен остаток от деления на 9, кроме тех случаев, когда остаток равен нулю. в этих случаях будет возвращенно число 9.

Вообще, в этом вопросе достаточно смысла, чтобы поговорить о нём и понять, понимает ли человек, как работают логические операторы в питоне (я - не понимал, пока не написал ответ :-)

Спасибо **dIm0n** за подсказки.

Comment: Что-то странное про "питоновский прикол" -- `print(0 or 1 or 2)` выводит `1`, а не `0`; `print(0 and 1 and 2)` выводит `0`, а не `2`

Comment: Вот, поэтому я и просил проверить ход млих рассуждений... Значит, в питоне, как и в других языках, 0 означает false, а читать это правило надо как "цепочка числовых операндов, связанных or, возвращает первое отличное от 0 значение". Ну, тогда ответ надо переделать.

Comment: Не совсем так, если `n%9` возвращает не ноль, то `n and 9` не будет рассматриваться

Comment: Вот сделал пару примеров для понимания https://repl.it/repls/UnevenTrickySign

Comment: Я прошу прощения, я всё прочитал, я понимаю, как это работает, я понимаю, ПОЧЕМУ так сделано (грубо говоря, потому, что если в цепочке "или" нашли "true" - то дальше проверять не надо, цепочка уже true), но я не понимаю, что в моём теперешнем ответе неправильно.

Comment: Сначала `%`, потом lhs для `or`, потом 1) либо выход, если lhs ненулевой; 2) либо `and` + rhs для `or`. А в ответе складывается впечатление, что `and` будет вызван всегда после `%`

Comment: @dIm0n, большое спасибо за внимательное отношение к этому вопросу, я не хочу спорить, я хочу разобраться :-). Я посмотрел раздел 6.17 доков по питончику ( https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html ), и там явно приоритет and больше, чем or. Мне кажется, это значит, что в выражении (n%9 or n and 9) вычисление (n and 9) имет приоритет над (n%9 or ...). Поправьте меня, возможно, я ошибаюсь. Спасибо!

Comment: Я в примере вроде это показал. [Вот](https://repl.it/repls/NearCoolThings), смотрите, если бы было так как вы говорите, то была бы строка `bool` в 1 варианте. Больший приоритет говорит о том, что будет вычисляться `n and 9`, а не `(n%9 or n) and 9`

Comment: Большое спасибо, я не уверен, что въехал правильно в это. По моему, мы говорим разными словами об одном и том же. То, что сначала вычисляется то, что входит в and, и только потом то, что входит в or, не вызывает сомнений.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы считаете, что `n and 9` будет выполняться всегда, независимо от того, будет ли оно в итоге входить в ответ или нет из-за большего приоритета `and`. Это так? Если нет, то всё правильно, но из ответа складывается впечатление, что это так, стоит как-то описать это

Comment: Вот теперь я въехал. Вот это - реально тонкий момент. Да, я ошибался, мне казалось, что, по аналогии с примитиным приоритетом опреаций, n and 9 будет выполняться всегда, потому что "приоритет то выше". Но на самом деле, как я теперь понял, если у первого аргумента (который стоит перед or) ненулевое значение - то да, всё остальное не будет рассматриваться. Еще раз спасибо. Вопрос - прекрасный пример того, как человек спросил и исчел, а двое не самых глупых стековерфлововцев остались и один чему то научил другого :-)

Comment: @dIm0n, `print(0 or 1 or 2)` тут `1` вернется, т.к. используется `or` а ему хватает первого значения, что будет булевым `True` (`2 or 3 or 1` -> `2`), т.е. `1`, противоположное с `and` -- вернется первое значение аналогичное `False` или последнее среди значений с `and`, среди которых все `True` (`2 and 1 and 3` -> `3`, `2 and 0 and 3` -> `0`)

Comment: @gil9red ну да, всё правильно